# How to implement an input/output inside a simple filesystem kernel module via memory pages?

Tags: io, filesystems, paging, kernel-module, kernel

I am trying to implement a very simple filesystem driver kernel module. All it has to do is to create a file inside a mount folder and provide it with read/write access to mounted device. Let us have a loop device, which is connected to some file. Then, if this device is mounted to some directory using the new filesystem type, the user shall be able to read/write/modify the file connected to the loop using the single filesystem file as a kind of interface. Access to a file should be implemented using memory pages mechanism.

So far, I've managed to successfully create a FS single file. I have inodes and dentries for root and a file inside the root folder. 
Now I need to provide operations for file access. So, I've created a `file_operations` type structure to use as my file `inode->f_ops`. 
It has `read/write/aio_read/aio_write` functions, but `read` function simply calls `do_sync_read` and `aio_read` is a `generic_file_aio_read`. That's also true for writing.

```
static struct file_operations fs_file_ops = {
    .read       = do_sync_read,
    .aio_read   = generic_file_aio_read,
    .write      = do_sync_write,
    .aio_write  = generic_file_aio_write,
}
```

Also, I've created an `address_space_operations` structure to use as `inode->i_mapping->a_ops`. It has `readpage` and `writepage` functions. My `readpage` implementation calls `mpage_readpage` standard function. `mpage_readpage` is called with `readpage` `page` argument and `get_block` function.

```
static struct address_space_operations fs_aops = {
    .readpage = fs_readpage,
    .writepage = fs_writepage 
};

static int fs_readpage(struct file *file, struct page *page)
{
     return mpage_readpage(page, fs_get_block);
}
```

`get_block` function maps superblock to buffer and provides blocks for memory pages processing and it is implemented in a following way:

```
static int fs_get_block(struct inode *inode, sector_t block, struct buffer_head *bh, int create)
{
    map_bh(bh, inode->i_sb, block);
    size_t i_b_size = bh->b_size >> inode->i_blkbits;
    size_t r_b_size = i_size_read(inode) >> inode->i_blkbits - block;
    bh->b_size = min(i_b_size, r_b_size) << inode->i_blkbits;
    return 0;
}
```

So, when user is trying to read something from file, `do_sync_read` is called, which uses `generic_file_aio_read`. It calls for `readpage` function, and `readpage` function calls for `mpage_readpage`, which takes `fs_get_block` as an argument, which provides a block for pages. This functions should implement reading a file page by page.

The problem is, for now I haven't managed to get the needed output from FS file. So, what is wrong with my implementation? If it is incomplete, then what functions should I also implement in my module to make it work? Or, maybe, the problem is with my implementation of `get_block`?